# How to test svelte input attribute agains multiple options

Tags: javascript, json, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-store

i have store value and two sets of data:

```
$selectedColor

const productColor = {
   options: [
      {id:0, title: 'white'},
      {id:1, title: 'black'},
      {id:2, title: 'red'},
      {id:3, title: 'yellow'}
   ],
}


const productType = {
   options: [
      {id:0, title: 'somethings', hiddenInColor: 'white'},
      {id:1, title: 'somethings', hiddenInColor: 'black'},
      {
         id:2, 
         title: 'somethings', 
         hiddenInColor: 
        //here should be black AND white
        //problem is I can't understand how to use nested json with disable attribute (see below) 
      }
   ],
}
```

then i have populate  inputs (type: radio) for product type and color

```
{#each productType.options as option (option.id)}
            {#if activeTab !== option.hiddenIn}
                <li>
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="name" 
                            value={option.id} 
                            on:change={() => optionHasChanged(option.name, somethings)}
                            disabled={option.hiddenInColor == $selectedColor}
                            bind:group={defaultProductType}>
                        {option.title}
                    </label>
                </li>
            {/if}
        {/each}
```

I was trying to -> disable input IF $selectedColor == hiddenInColor

i did it like this ->

```
disabled={option.hiddenInColor == $selectedColor}
```

and it works well. But... only when you testing it against 1 value

i cant understand how to check more then 1 color at once.
So basically, using my const productType ->
i would like to disable id:3 if $selectedColor == 'black' || 'white'

any advices? Or maybe there is more compact solution to this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this would be using an array `hiddenInColors` instead of a single scalar value:

```js
const productType = {
   options: [
      {id:0, title: 'somethings', hiddenInColors: ['white']},
      {id:1, title: 'somethings', hiddenInColors: ['black']},
      {id:2, title: 'somethings', hiddenInColors: ['black','white']},
   ],
}
```

and then set the disabled option like this:

```js
disabled={option.hiddenInColors.includes($selectedColor)}
```

Comment: Hi @Thomas Hennes, really appreciate your effort.
But with :
disabled={option.hiddenInColors.includes($selectedColor)}
im always see an TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')
Default value for $selectedColor exist because :
disabled={option.hiddenInColor == $selectedColor} 
is working

Comment: That would mean `hiddenInColors` is not set or not an array. Check your code for typos. Remember you have to set single colors in an array as well, as I did in my answer.

Comment: you'r right. There was a typo issue..thanks a lot for you time.